# Как работает этот массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

for (var i = 0; i < (array.length / 2); i++) {
  array[i] = [array[i], array[array.length - i - 1]];
  array[array.length - i - 1] = array[i][0];
  array[i] = array[i][1];
}

console.log( array );
```

Народ помогите разобраться с массивом. Понимаю какой будет в итоге результат, но не понимаю как работает.

Например: `array[array.length - i - 1]` - Почему мы получаем здесь 8-ку? Чему здесь равняется `i`?
`-1` - это мы отбрасываем последнюю ячейку?

Comment: Распишите по шагам. Что происходит?

Comment: Код разворачивает массив задом-наперед. Вся эта возня с записыванием массива из двух элементов в `array[i]` - для того, чтобы не заводить временную переменную.

Comment: можете обьяснить как работает?

Comment: Почему Вы не хотите расписать по итерациям, что происходит внутри Вашего кода во время выполнения цикла? Что будет от того, что Вам всё объяснят? Вы всё равно сути не поймёте, пока не сделаете сами.

Comment: Дело в том что я только начал изучать js. Не не хочу - не знаю как)

Comment: @hedgehogues подскажите как расписать по итерациям?

Comment: @Евгений, пусть i == 0. Что происходит в теле? Пусть i == 1. Что происходит в теле? И т.д. пока i < array.length / 2.

Comment: @hedgehogues да в том то и дело, что я не понимаю что происходит в теле при i == 0 и т.д.

Comment: Форматируйте код с помощью отступов в 4 пробела, также вы можете выделить отрывок кода в сообщении и нажать сочетание Ctrl+K, чтобы добавить или удалить отступ.

Comment: В чём проблема? Вы понимаете, что такое массив?

Comment: @hedgehogues да - это набор какой-то информации например чисел или строк, разделенных запятой

Comment: @Евгений, нет, Вы не понимаете, что такое массив. Читайте: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) Как прочтёте, пишите.

Comment: @hedgehogues как сказал классик - "Знаете ли вы украинскую ночь? Нет, вы не знаете украинской ночи!"

Answer (score 1):

Индекс массива начинается с нуля, т.е. первая ячейка соответствует индексу 0, последняя - 7.
Длинна массива равняется 8. Если мы попробуем из нашего массива получить значение

```
array[8];
```

получим ошибку, ведь мы уже знаем что наш массив проиндексирован от 0 до 7.
Вычисление индекса `array[array.length - i - 1]` при первой итерации даст нам значение равное 7. Всё равно что обратиться к ячейке `array[7]`, которая содержит цифру 8. Далее при завершении первой итерации цикл for прибавит к i единицу.

Answer (score 0):

Работает так же, как

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var temp;
for (var i = 0; i < (array.length / 2); i++) {
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - i - 1];
    array[array.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
document.write(array);
```

Т.е. зеркально переставляет элементы массива.

Но дольше.